# How can I automate build of multiple swfs from Flash Builder 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm working on a project that has a Main.fla and a Preload.fla. I am doing all the coding in Flash Builder 4. Each time I want to test I have to go to Flash CS5, publish Main.swf and then run Preload.swf. Is there a way to automate this process so I can just press the "Run Main" button inside Flash Builder 4 and all that is done automatically?

Comment: I just design the Main in such a way that it can be run either on its own, or loaded from within Preloader. This usually requires a little logic in the Main docclass like "if context != preloader { some functionality }" but not always. Could be an option for you if you don't figure out the automatic build functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSFL script to compile all your fla's.  Then set up the JSFL as an external tool in Flash Builder.

Comment: I created the JSFL file and it runs fine in the Flash IDE but when I try to add it as an external tool I get an error saying the file cannot execute.

Comment: When you setup the external tool did you point it directly to the jsfl or to flash.exe with jsfl as a command line parameter?  Are there any spaces in the path?  If you're on windows, try using short dos names for the path instead of one with spaces.

Comment: I'm on a mac. It seems the External Tools does not recognize Flash.app as a file that can be run. I tried putting Flash.exe in as a test and the error about the file not existing went away. Is this a bug or is this functionality not allowed on a mac?

Comment: @knuckfubuck, sorry, I can't help you with a mac.  Try asking a new question specifically about running external tools in Eclipse on a mac.